# Excel - Add space between number and word

Tags: excel

I am looking for a way to put a space in between a text value and numerical value, but there is a hitch. Sometimes the text might start with a number as well and I don't want this to contain the space. For Example

```
Col A                 Col B
Name1:3-2             Name 1:3-2
Name6:5,4             Name 6:5,4
1 Val55:12-4          1 Val 55:12-4
2 Val 22:43           2 Val 22:43
Name10                Name 10
```

Where Col A is the value and Col B contains the formula to add the space to the value is Col A.

Few things to Note here:

1. The space is always added to only the first number after the text ends.
2. If the value starts with a number that one should be ignored and again the first number after the text should have the space added to it
3. If there is already a space, another should not be added.
4. The length of the text before the numbers varies
5. There isn't always a : between values after the first number

The data set I am working with is about 1,000 entries so speed is not necessary just need something that works for all cases as I don't want to go through that many entries and add a space.

**EDIT** Final Solution Thanks to Gary's Student below:

```
' Function Assumes that there are atleast 2 characters in front of the expected space
' Function Assumes that there are no numbers within the text that will cause an early splitting of characters
Public Function SpacedOut(sIn As String) As String
    Dim L As Long, i As Long, Done As Boolean
    Dim sOut As String
    L = Len(sIn)
    Done = False
    sOut = Left(sIn, 1)
    ' Skips the first possible number if it is there if not, we are safe to start at 2
    ' Since there will always be more than one character prior to the expected first number
    For i = 2 To L
        ' Check for a number without a space before it
        If Mid(sIn, i - 1, 1) <> " " And Mid(sIn, i, 1) Like "[0-9]" And Not Done Then
            Done = True
            sOut = sOut & " " & Mid(sIn, i, 1)
        ' Check for a space with a number after it and continue on if this is found
        ElseIf Mid(sIn, i - 1, 1) = " " And Mid(sIn, i, 1) Like "[0-9]" And Not Done Then
            Done = True
            sOut = sOut & Mid(sIn, i, 1)
        ' Append next character
        Else
            sOut = sOut & Mid(sIn, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    SpacedOut = sOut
End Function
```

Thanks,
DMan

Comment: If space is needed after values: "Name" and "Val", we could use find and replace?

Comment: So Column A is what you *have* and Column B is what you *want*. Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this small **UDF** :

```
Public Function SpacedOut(sIn As String) As String
    Dim L As Long, i As Long, Done As Boolean
    Dim sOut As String
    L = Len(sIn)
    Done = False
    sOut = Left(sIn, 1)
    For i = 2 To L
        If Mid(sIn, i - 1, 1) Like "[a-zA-Z]" And Mid(sIn, i, 1) Like "[0-9]" And Not Done Then
            Done = True
            sOut = sOut & " " & Mid(sIn, i, 1)
        Else
            sOut = sOut & Mid(sIn, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    SpacedOut = sOut
End Function
```

**EDIT#1:**

Here is a snap of my VBE screen with the module hi-lighted:

[image: SNAP]

Comment: Works perfectly .this is what OP want it seems :)

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer I will give it a try. Can you please advice on how to use macros in google spreadsheets? or do I need to transfer the result to Excel then back to google spreadsheets?

Comment: I also would like to know how to run macros in Google Docs!

Comment: Haha alright well with that said how do I do it in Excel 2010? I added in development tools, enable scripts and added the module. When I go to use the function I just get #Name? in the field indicating it doesn't know that name for the function. It does show up in the list of available functions though. Maybe my character set is not supported. Here is a sample of a live piece of data maybe you can help with getting it separated 创世记1:1

Comment: That error message means that Excel can't find the UDF! ....... make sure it is in a standard module ............ make sure you are using it like: ** =SpacedOut(B9) ** .

Comment: Can you please advise on how to see if it is standard? also I am using it that way without the *'s around it. The name shows up as an available function.

Comment: Sweet that works now (I apparently needed to enable macros still even tho I already did it asked me to when I saved). Now is there any way to make it match a character of any language? I will be using this to expand the languages of an app and currently I need it for Chinese but the above doesn't support that character set. I will mark as answer after this last piece, I should have specified in question more my apologies.

Comment: Alright so I figured something out to go with it. Thanks a lot Gary's Student. The tweak I made can be found in my Edit above. Thank you very much for all your help! Added bonus comment too to help others see whats going on :D